# How can you ensure a property is always present for a graphql query using createNode in Gatsby

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, gatsby

`createNode` will not create fields if its value is null. We have a ephemeral data feed that sometimes returns objects where some fields are null, although it is rare.

We want to use this query, but because sometimes the `name` is null  gatsby will remove it and cause this query to error.

```html
{
  allMyType {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        name
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

Is there any way around this issue?

This code simulates the usecase:

```js
const crypto = require('crypto')
exports.createPages = ({ boundActionCreators, graphql }) => {
  const { createNode } = boundActionCreators
  // Simulate an ephemeral data source that sometimes doesn't have all properties set
  const data = {
    id: '1',
    name: Math.random() < 0.5 ? null : 'Paul Serby' 
  }
  createNode({
    ...data,
    id: data.id,
    children: [],
    parent: null,
    internal: {
      type: 'MyType',
      contentDigest: crypto
        .createHash(`md5`)
        .update(JSON.stringify(data))
        .digest(`hex`)
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Gatsby skips `null` values.

It builds the schema from your source data and ignores nulls, so if every single field in your incoming data is empty or `null`, then the field does not get created. [This issue](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/3913) suggests that there are cases where sparsely populated fields might also get ignored. If you can set the field to an empty string instead of `null` (maybe in your source plugin) that might provide a workaround.